# Linked list not printing the value? What am i doing wrong

Tags: c++

i am having trouble debugging my program.For some odd reason I cannot print the value of subscription in my linked list.

```
/*Player.h
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player
{   
    double  subscription; /*value to be stored*/
public:
    Player(); /*default constructor*/
    Player(double); //double
    ~Player();
    double getSubscription(){ return subscription; }
};
#endif
```

Comment: I don't like the use of `malloc` in your c++ code, you should at least use `new`

Comment: You do not need to repeat the `struct` with each variable declaration. In C++, a `struct` declaration automatically names a type that can be used by itself. Also, `malloc` should rarely be used in C++ because it does not call the constructor of a class and `free` will not call the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in SoccerClub.cpp on the line:

```
player = &Player(subscription); /*store the subscription into player using the constructor*/
```

This is creating a Player object and assigning the address of that object to the pointer *player*, but at the end of the full expression (by the next line), this object goes out of scope and is destructed. This is not using the memory that you allocated with malloc earlier.

Remove the malloc and use:

```
player = new Player(subscription);
```

just make sure to call *delete* later to destruct this object and free up the memory.

Comment: Just wrote a quick test program. This is exactly what is happening.

Comment: No, don't do that. Use a smart pointer. And also your scoping is wrong. C++ temporaries are scoped to the *full expression* they are contained in, which in most cases means scoped to the statement- *not* the function.

Comment: @Puppy You're correct, it is the expression, not the function. I corrected my answer with that.
Smart pointers are an option that help to prevent memory leaks, but they are not the only way to fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I see couple of problems in the following line (in `SoccerClub::AddPlayer`):.

```
player = &Player(subscription); /*store the subscription into player using the constructor*/
```

1. You are storing a pointer to a function local object. The pointer will be a dangling pointer once the function returns.
2. You've just leaked memory from the previous `malloc` call used
   to allocate memory for player.

Other problems I see.

You are using `malloc` to allocate memory for the objects. That does not initialize the objects properly. The constructors don't get called. You *must* replace them by calls to `new`.

E.g.

Replace

```
player = (struct Player *) malloc(sizeof(struct Player));
```

by

```
player = new Player(...); // No need to use struct Player, just Player
                          // Provide the right arguments to the constructors
```

Replace

```
temp = (struct Link *) malloc(sizeof(struct Link)); /*allocate memory*/
```

by

```
temp = new Link(...); // No need to use struct Link, just Link
                      // Provide the right arguments to the constructors
```

Comment: @ R Sahu should I just leave the Link constructor blank? when using player = new Player();

Comment: @bobsmith, I didn't follow that. `Player` does not have a `Link`. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, for player = new Player(). Should I leave Player() arguments blank?.